# JS and CSS not loading in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been following this article (https://dev.to/programliftoff/create-a-basic-webpage-with-css-and-javascript--104i) to get started on building an interactive webpage, but I can't get the JS and CSS to work.

I'm working in Sublime, and I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqD5C77Tk3I&feature=youtu.be) to run it through http rather than the file system.

I've double checked the folder paths fifty times (they're just saved on my desktop as 'scripts' and 'styles' in the same folder as my index.html doc), and tried different variations of dots at the start of the paths and slashes both ways, but the JS and CSS just won't load. I've also moved the 'link rel' and 'scripts async src' lines between the head and body tags, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

My html doc looks like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel=“stylesheet” type="text/css" href=“../styles/styles.css” />
    <script async src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Hello, World</h1>
  <h4 id=‘date’></h4>
  <img src="images/IMG_4945.jpg" alt="My test image">
</html>
```

My JS doc looks like this,

```
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();
```

My CSS doc looks like this,

```
body {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #ffe6e6;
}
```

Comment: You havent closed your body before your `</html>` mate :) Do `</body>` before your closing HTML tag

Comment: I notice some of your single and double quotes are the 'fancy' kind.  Maybe that's causing an issue?  Sometimes that happens when you copy-paste code from a webpage.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs actually I don't think they are.  I think they're 'smart quotes'  https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html   backticks are different.  If they were backticks they'd tilt the same way at both ends.

Comment: @MrVimes oh snap - you're right - didn't even see that they're going to the right! Never seen these quotes before :) will rm comment

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without looking at your file structure, but let's assume you have it like this:

```
|-Project
|-----css
|---------style.css
|-----js
|---------main.js
|-----index.html
```

in your index.html you should be calling your css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

in UNIX based OS's (and localhost Windows) `/` equates to document root. It's best to do this as you're guranteed to always call that file no matter where you copy + paste code to.

Note: In Windows servers `/` doesn't work - not sure why. Windows just sucks I guess.

Comment: What if the styles folder is in the parent folder as in OP's original code? Yours is a supposition, not an answer.

Comment: @Alberto then it still works ... it's always best to use full urls - htaccess and server conf isn't always configured to use `../` links and require absolute urls

Comment: @Alberto yes ... yes it does. Only case it won't work is if CSS/JS files are stored outside of the project folder - in which case .. OP should restructure project so it includes the assets

Comment: So again, yours is a supposition, not an answer to OP's issue.

Comment: @Alberto no where does OP mention code is stored outside of project folder .. so it's an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the async keyword from your script element. That isn't an asynchronous script and it modifies the DOM before it's ready.

Use jQuery `$(document).ready(function() {});` or JS `window.onload = function() {};` and remove that async attribute so your script is run in synch with the DOM.

In other words, you cannot edit the document before it has been created. But you are trying to do that with an async and no check for if the document is ready.

Answer (score -1):

`../` means parent folder. So:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" />
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

Double quotation marks in your code are valid? `“` -> `"` Pls check it.